# Cuda : Reduce (max/min) function on matrix implementation

Tags: cuda

So I am working on a reduce function on a matrix : I need to find the max value in a matrix. I have implemented a function to get the max on an array and transforming it to a matrix version should be straightforward but I can't get it to work. I am wondering if this is the right approach. You can find the code for the two versions below :

For an array :

```
__global__
void reduce_kernal_shared_mem(float *d_in, float *d_out){
    int indx = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int tindx = threadIdx.x;

    extern __shared__ float sh_in[];

    sh_in[tindx] = -99999.0f;

    sh_in[tindx] = d_in[indx];
    __syncthreads();

    for(int i = blockDim.x / 2; i > 0; i >>= 1){
        if(tindx < i){
            sh_in[tindx] = fmax(sh_in[tindx], sh_in[tindx + i]);
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    if(tindx == 0){
        d_out[blockIdx.x] = sh_in[0];
    }
}

void reduce(float *d_in, float *d_int, float *d_out, const int ARRAY_SIZE, bool is_shared){
    if(!is_shared){
        reduce_kernal<<<1024, 1024>>>(d_in, d_int);
        reduce_kernal<<<1, 1024>>>(d_int, d_out);
    }else{
        reduce_kernal_shared_mem<<<1024, 1024, 1024 * sizeof(float)>>>(d_in, d_int);
        reduce_kernal_shared_mem<<<1, 1024, 1024 * sizeof(float)>>>(d_int, d_out);
    }
}
```

For a matrix :

```
__global__
void get_max(const float* d_logLuminance, float *d_out, int numRows, int numCols){
   int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
   int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
   int c_t = threadIdx.x;
   int r_t = threadIdx.y;
   int pos_1D = row * numCols + col;
   int pos_1D_t = r_t * blockDim.x + c_t;

   extern __shared__ float sh_mem[];

   sh_mem[pos_1D_t] = -999999.0f;

   if(pos_1D > numCols * numRows)
      return;

   sh_mem[pos_1D_t] = d_logLuminance[pos_1D];
   __syncthreads();

   for(int s = (blockDim.x * blockDim.y) / 2; s > 0; s >>= 1){
      if(pos_1D_t < s)
         sh_mem[pos_1D_t] = fmax(sh_mem[pos_1D_t], sh_mem[pos_1D_t + s]);
      __syncthreads();
   }

   if(r_t == 0 && c_t == 0)
      d_out[blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.x] = sh_mem[0];
}

void max(const float *d_logLuminance, int numRows, int numCols, float &max_logLum){

   int THREADS_PER_BLOCK = 32;
   dim3 blockSize(THREADS_PER_BLOCK, THREADS_PER_BLOCK);
   dim3 gridSize((THREADS_PER_BLOCK + numCols - 1) / THREADS_PER_BLOCK, 
                  (THREADS_PER_BLOCK + numRows - 1) / THREADS_PER_BLOCK);

   float *d_out, *d_int;
   cudaMalloc(&d_out, sizeof(float) * numRows * numCols);
   cudaMalloc(&d_int, sizeof(float) * numRows * numCols);


   get_max<<<gridSize, blockSize, THREADS_PER_BLOCK * THREADS_PER_BLOCK * sizeof(float)>>>(d_logLuminance, d_int, numRows, numCols);
   get_max<<<1, blockSize, THREADS_PER_BLOCK * THREADS_PER_BLOCK * sizeof(float)>>>(d_int, d_out, numRows, numCols);

   cudaDeviceSynchronize();

   cudaMemcpy(&max_logLum, d_out, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

   printf("max : %f\n", max_logLum);

   cudaFree(d_out);
   cudaFree(d_int);

}
```

The expected result calculated in serial algorithm is 2.18911 while the parallel reduce function outputs 1.319142 .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither of the codes you have shown are well-optimized for performance.  Writing a fast parallel reduction on the GPU will typically have a number of salient characteristics:

1. It will use a [grid-stride loop](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/), with an optimally chosen number of threads, [to accumulate partial per-thread results](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf), consuming the entire data set.
2. In lieu of shared-memory sweep-style reduction, it will use a 2-stage [warp-shuffle approach](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/faster-parallel-reductions-kepler/), to combine the per-thread results in each threadblock into a partial per-threadblock result.
3. It will dispense with the usual 2-kernel-launch approach to combine the per-threadblock results.  Instead, either a final one-per-threadblock atomic operation will be used to update a global variable (e.g. if a suitable atomic operation corresponding to the desired reduction operation is available) or else it will use a threadblock-draining methodology ("[threadfence reduction](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#threadfencereduction)"), to allow the "last" threadblock in the kernel launch to complete the final reduction to a single quantity.

So to address technical issues in your kernel, let's keep in mind that this is a learning exercise.  I'm not suggesting your approach (either one) is the best way to do it.

You have both illegal behavior as well as design issues to consider in your 2D kernel approach:

1. This construct:

   ```
   if(pos_1D > numCols * numRows)
     return;                        // this return statement creates a hazard

   sh_mem[pos_1D_t] = d_logLuminance[pos_1D];
   __syncthreads();                 // ... at this call
   ```

   allows for the possibility of undefined behavior.  CUDA requires that `__syncthreads()` be reached by all threads in the threadblock.  However the `return` statement may allow certain threads in certain threadblocks to early-exit, which means they won't participate in the call to `__syncthreads()`.  This is an [illegal design pattern](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization-functions).
2. Your 2D design limits the maximum size data set to dimensions of 32x32 blocks or 1024x1024 data set size.  To see why this is, observe that the 2nd kernel launch could have a maximum of 1024 threads, and since one thread corresponds to one threadblock in the previous launch, the previous launch can have a maximum of 32x32 = 1024 threadblocks.  The code could be reworked to remove this limitation, however my intent here is to suggest that if you want to write a fast, robust parallel reduction, nearly every aspect of your design must be reworked, therefore I suggest starting over with the characteristics I outlined at the beginning.
3. Your 2nd kernel launch isn't constructed correctly:

   ```
   get_max<<<1, blockSize, THREADS_PER_BLOCK * THREADS_PER_BLOCK * sizeof(float)>>>(d_int, d_out, numRows, numCols);
   ```

   the size of the data set at this point is no longer `numRows`*`numCols`.  It has been reduced to some value that is 32x32 or less.  You have several other similar sizing issues in your code.

Here is a modified version of your code that has the above issues addressed.  I did not detail every single change I made to your code, so please study the differences in addition to the 3 items listed above:

```
$ cat t1490.cu
#include <stdio.h>

__global__
void get_max(const float* d_logLuminance, float *d_out, int numRows, int numCols){
   int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
   int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
   int c_t = threadIdx.x;
   int r_t = threadIdx.y;
   int pos_1D = row * numCols + col;
   int pos_1D_t = r_t * blockDim.x + c_t;

   extern __shared__ float sh_mem[];

   sh_mem[pos_1D_t] = (pos_1D >= numCols * numRows)?-999999.0f:d_logLuminance[pos_1D];
   __syncthreads();

   for(int s = (blockDim.x * blockDim.y) / 2; s > 0; s >>= 1){
      if(pos_1D_t < s)
         sh_mem[pos_1D_t] = fmax(sh_mem[pos_1D_t], sh_mem[pos_1D_t + s]);
      __syncthreads();
   }

   if(r_t == 0 && c_t == 0)
      d_out[blockIdx.y * gridDim.x + blockIdx.x] = sh_mem[0];
}

void max(const float *d_logLuminance, int numRows, int numCols, float &max_logLum){

   int THREADS_PER_BLOCK = 32;
   dim3 blockSize(THREADS_PER_BLOCK, THREADS_PER_BLOCK);
   dim3 gridSize((THREADS_PER_BLOCK + numCols - 1) / THREADS_PER_BLOCK,
                  (THREADS_PER_BLOCK + numRows - 1) / THREADS_PER_BLOCK);

   float *d_out, *d_int;
   cudaMalloc(&d_out, sizeof(float));
   cudaMalloc(&d_int, sizeof(float) * gridSize.y*gridSize.x);


   get_max<<<gridSize, blockSize, THREADS_PER_BLOCK * THREADS_PER_BLOCK * sizeof(float)>>>(d_logLuminance, d_int, numRows, numCols);
   get_max<<<1, blockSize, THREADS_PER_BLOCK * THREADS_PER_BLOCK * sizeof(float)>>>(d_int, d_out, gridSize.y, gridSize.x);

   cudaDeviceSynchronize();

   cudaMemcpy(&max_logLum, d_out, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

   printf("max : %f\n", max_logLum);

   cudaFree(d_out);
   cudaFree(d_int);

}

int main(){

   int sx = 1024;
   int sy = 1024;
   float *d_data, result = 2.18911;
   cudaMalloc(&d_data, sx*sy*sizeof(d_data[0]));
   cudaMemset(d_data, 0, sx*sy*sizeof(d_data[0]));
   cudaMemcpy(d_data, &result, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   result = 0;
   max(d_data, sy, sx, result);
}
$ nvcc -o t1490 t1490.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1490
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
max : 2.189110
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Note that you haven't provided a complete code.  It's always possible that you also have errors in the code you haven't shown.  In my answer I have provided an example of a compelete code.